# What sets the MAG of a BJT?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, rf, bjt

Suppose you design ideal matching networks on the input and output of your transistor so ALL we're concerned with is the transistor and the packaging.

What semiconductor physics or parasitics or whatever sets the MAG figure in the datasheet?

I tried doing a few back of the envelope calculations: one by looking at the y parameters of the hybrid-pi model and looking at the unilateral gain.

This showed a dependence on the early voltage and beta (specifically, I get \$\ \frac{\beta V_a}{4 V_t}\$ ), but this figure was way too high (40 dB).

I also tried calculating the maximum stable gain given the parasitic base-emitter capacitance and the Barkhausen criteria (resulted in something looking like \$ G = (C_{be} Z_0 \omega)^{-2} \$), plugging in some sensible values gave a gain of somewhere between 20-30 dB, which seems better, but from what I understand, you can just add an inductor to resonate with this capacitance to stabilize the transistor and this is no longer a limit.

- When MAG is measured, is this considered?
- For whatever limits this MAG, could you point me to a reference where
  this is modeled somewhat concretely?

I realize this might just be one
   of those things that just is really hard to model, but I really feel
   the need to have some back of the envelope calculation to ballpark
   this with some numbers.

I'm not particularly interested in answers
   that phrase this entirely in terms of the device's S-parameters at a
   certain frequency, unless you can explain why the gain is limited by
   this or that parameter, and then why that parameter is hard to make
   larger or smaller due to such-and-such reason.

Comment: It would help if you identified a specific datasheet and specific detail on it.

Comment: Let's maybe choose the MAG of the BFP183

Comment: Link to datasheet + specific text, table line, or chart to examine, please.

Comment: Gms from https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BFP183-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431400ef68011426706248060f

Comment: Specific text, table line, or chart to examine, and page, please. With the exact quantity shown there that you are examining...

Comment: Page 3, table subheading "AC Characteristics", line six

Comment: See pages 390-393 of "Microwave Circuit Design Using Linear and Nonlinear Techniques." 2nd edition.